# Filebeeat sending log, but logstash not running, connection refused! Logstash

Tags: logstash, filebeat

im used filebeat to many server, shipped nginx log to logstash
in this time and months my elk server is very good worked
but, my 1 line added grok pattern to syslog-filter.conf, and restart logstash ,,,
my elk and Concerning Logstash not worked
this is wehn, my elasticsearch and logatash and kibana ... services this up and enable and active!
but ...
my nginx servers ...
telnet to 5044
and
telnet to 5443
connection refused

this log, 1 server Logs (filebeat logs)

```
> 2018-01-23T10:21:21+03:30 ERR  Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.11.202:5443: getsockopt: connection refused
> 2018-01-23T10:21:28+03:30 INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: beat.memstats.gc_next=11769216 beat.memstats.memory_alloc=5935656 beat.memstats.memory_total=73881024 filebeat.harvester.open_files=5 filebeat.harvester.running=6 libbeat.config.module.running=0 libbeat.pipeline.clients=1 libbeat.pipeline.events.active=4117 libbeat.pipeline.events.retry=2048 registrar.states.current=35
> 2018-01-23T10:47:16+03:30 INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: beat.memstats.gc_next=11297792 beat.memstats.memory_alloc=5872352 beat.memstats.memory_total=26557112 filebeat.harvester.open_files=5 filebeat.harvester.running=6 libbeat.config.module.running=0 libbeat.pipeline.clients=1 libbeat.pipeline.events.active=4117 registrar.states.current=37
> 2018-01-23T10:47:22+03:30 ERR  Failed to connect: dial tcp 172.17.11.202:5443: getsockopt: connection refused
> 2018-01-23T10:47:46+03:30 INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: beat.memstats.gc_next=11297792 beat.memstats.memory_alloc=6012704 beat.memstats.memory_total=26697464 filebeat.harvester.open_files=5 filebeat.harvester.running=6 libbeat.config.module.running=0 libbeat.pipeline.clients=1 libbeat.pipeline.events.active=4117 libbeat.pipeline.events.retry=2048 registrar.states.current=37
> 2018-01-23T14:22:45+03:30 INFO Non-zero metrics in the last 30s: beat.info.uptime.ms=30000 beat.memstats.gc_next=11490800 beat.memstats.memory_alloc=5802160 beat.memstats.memory_total=153496216 filebeat.harvester.open_files=3 filebeat.harvester.running=2 libbeat.config.module.running=0 libbeat.pipeline.clients=1 libbeat.pipeline.events.active=4117 registrar.states.current=3
```

Comment: Please add logstash logs

Comment: thanks im fixed problem .

Comment: Thanks Thanks
im finding to problem ...
Inside the folder conf.d ...
my grok pattern ... conflicted
2 grok conflicted .
deleted last lined added, fix .